# How to keep an account active at the end of its payment due date in WooCommerce Subscriptions

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using WordPress 6.3.1 and WooCommerce Subscription 5.4.0.
I created a product with a variable subscription and payments in installments (1-4-10). This product is available until August 31, 2024 and my problem is the following:
if a user subscribes to the product with payment in 4 installments, at the end of these 4 months he no longer has access to the product while the product is still online. This problem also occurs with payments in 1 and 10 installments.
How can I still have access to this product at the end of its payment period and insert an end date of product availability?

I tried to change the WooCommerce and Woo subscription settings but I found nothing

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: This can't work as WooCommerce subscriptions is made for subscriptions but not for installments payments. Instead, you need to use [WooCommerce Deposits (commercial) plugin](https://woo.com/products/woocommerce-deposits/) that lets you set up installment plans on your online store. The plugin offers flexible payment options and allows you to offer custom schedules based on days, weeks, or months. You can create multiple payment plans for your WooCommerce store.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.